# datatable select max sum of two columns

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable, sum, max

I have a Datatable containing data like:

```
Id | Val1 | Val2
 0 |  0   |   1
 1 |  3   |   0
 2 |  0   |   3
 3 |  2   |   1
```

I need to know the MAX value of the SUM of Val1+Val2 (in the example table is 3) and then extract rows having these values.

I know how I can extract rows with:

```
MyTable.Select("(Val1 + Val2) = 3")
```

But I'm not able to get the max value of the sum so to put it into the "Select"

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to loop through the table to find the maximum sum, which could be done using LINQ:

```
Dim maxSum = (
    From r In MyTable.AsEnumerable()
    Select r.Field(Of Integer)("Val1") + r.Field(Of Integer)("Val2")
).Max()
```

And then just use that in your select:

```
MyTable.Select("(Val1 + Val2) = " & maxSum)
```

Comment: Thanks!, +1 for the logic but I've directly looped around the Datatable